# spline not match ExtrudeGeometry in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I create a closed spline and extrude geometry with rectangle shape to create a track for my game. I use spline to calculate the position of my ship, but when I check, the spline does not match completely with the geometry. Is there something wrong?

[shape used to extrude example](http://snag.gy/GLyeG.jpg)

[extrude geometry and spline not match](http://snag.gy/cWCXw.jpg)

Here is my code:

```
var genTrack = function (lanes, controlPoints, material, isClose) {

//extrude setting
var extrudeSettings = {
    bevelEnabled: true,
    bevelSegments: 2,
    steps: 200,
    material: 1,
    extrudeMaterial: 1
};

//track shape
var trackShape = new THREE.Shape([
    new THREE.Vector2(-config.laneHeight/2, config.laneWidth/2),
    new THREE.Vector2(-config.laneHeight/2, - config.laneWidth/2),
    new THREE.Vector2(config.laneHeight/2, - config.laneWidth/2),
    new THREE.Vector2(config.laneHeight/2, config.laneWidth/2),
]);
//spline
if (isClose)
    var spline = new THREE.ClosedSplineCurve3(controlPoints);
else
    var spline = new THREE.SplineCurve3(controlPoints);

utils.public('spline', spline);
//set path
extrudeSettings.extrudePath = spline;

//frenet
var frenet = new THREE.TubeGeometry.FrenetFrames(spline, 200, false)
extrudeSettings.frames = frenet;
utils.public('extrudeSettings', extrudeSettings);

//create geometry
var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry(trackShape, extrudeSettings);

var splineGeo = new THREE.TubeGeometry(spline, 200, 1, 4, true, false);

utils.public('frenet', frenet);
var angle = 0;
var track = new THREE.Object3D();
track.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
track.receiveShadow = true;
for (var i=0; i< lanes; i++){
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    mesh.position.set(i * (config.laneSpan + config.laneWidth), -30, 0);
    //mesh.rotation.set(0, 0,angle);
    //angle += Math.PI/180 * 20;
    track.add(mesh);
}
track.scale.set(1.5, 1.5, 1.5);
var splineMesh = new THREE.Mesh(splineGeo, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff}));
return {
    'geometry': geometry,
    'mesh': track,
    'spline': spline,
    'frenet': frenet,
    'splineMesh': splineMesh,
    'controlPoints' : controlPoints
};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is with this line:

```
mesh.position.set(i * (config.laneSpan + config.laneWidth), -30, 0);
```

I think what you want is something more like:

```
mesh.position.set(i * config.laneWidth / lanes, config.laneHeight / 2, 0);
```

I haven't tested it, but I think you need something like this.

Comment: thank you for your advice and reply :D. But it not help to fix problem.

Comment: Sorry. It's realy where cause my problem. I want to sure my ship always over the track so i translate it down. It's not true because my spline is random. Just fix : mesh.position.set(i * (config.laneSpan + config.laneWidth), 0, 0); and change the rectangle. Thanks you

Comment: Ah, got it. Well, glad I could help find the trouble line at least.